# Conditionally update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a SQL Server stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_CONTRACT
  @contractId     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  @name           VARCHAR(256) = NULL,
  @description    VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @effectiveDate  DATETIME2 = NULL,
  @expirationDate DATETIME2 = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE CONTRACT
  SET    NAME = ISNULL(@name, NAME),
         DESCRIPTION = ISNULL(@description, DESCRIPTION),
         EFFECTIVE_DATE = ISNULL(@effectiveDate, EFFECTIVE_DATE),
         EXPIRATION_DATE = ISNULL(@expirationDate, EXPIRATION_DATE),
  WHERE  CONTRACT_ID = @contractId
END
GO
```

As is, this allows me to optionally update any of the fields by supplying a value for that parameter or not. But what if I also want to be able to set the expiration date to NULL itself? I have to give all the parameters a default value of NULL or else it will complain that I did not provide that parameter if I am not updating it.

The only way I can think of doing that is to have a separate parameter like `@noExpiration` and if that is supplied, then set EXPIRATION_DATE = NULL. That's fine for this specific case, but what if I had many more fields that could also potentially be null? The only solution for that I can think of is to not even have this single stored procedure, and just conditionally make an update statement for each field separately.

Is there a more elegant/common way of handling this?

**Update:**
For more context, this is how the procedure is used.

This procedure is called from an express app using the mssql library. Something like:

```js
router.patch('/updateContract', (req, res) => {
  const {
    contractId,
    name,
    description,
    effectiveDate,
    expirationDate
  } = req.body;

  const request = new sql.Request();

  request.input('contractId', sql.Int, contractId);
  
  if (name)
    request.input('name', sql.VarChar, name);

  if (description)
    request.input('description', sql.VarChar, description);

  if (effectiveDate)
    request.input('effectiveDate', sql.DateTime, effectiveDate);

  if (expirationDate)
    request.input('expirationDate', sql.DateTime, expirationDate);

  request.execute('UPDATE_CONTRACT', (err, result) => {...
```

When the frontend application wants to update a contract, it will call updateContract and supply only the relevant fields that are being updated, along with the contractId. When the procedure is called, those left out parameters will default to null and therefore be ignored. So the issue here is that null is a valid value for expirationDate. I need to do something like this, which works but seems cumbersome if there are more params that are nullable. It would be convenient if sql had an undefined value that could be set as the default values so that null could be used as a legit value.

```js
if (expirationDate === null)
  request.input('noExpiration', sql.Int, 1);
else if (expirationDate)
  request.input('expirationDate', sql.DateTime, expirationDate);
```

Comment: Well I wouldn't recommend this, but if have a known invalid value you could use that as the default and only update the column if the value passed in is not the default e.g. `@expirationDate DATETIME2 = '01-Jan-1900'` and `case when @expirationDate = '01-Jan-1900' then EXPIRATION_DATE else @expirationDate end`

Comment: *The only way I can think of doing that is to have a separate parameter like @noExpiration and if that is supplied, then set EXPIRATION_DATE = NULL ... Is there a more elegant/common way of handling this?* No, thats probably the best way.

Comment: It's very hard to code 3 different values of information in tsql because it only has 2 available, null and not null. One school of thought is to remove nulls and use some sentient values for lack of info (19000101,'',0 or - 1), which would allow you to code lack of parameter values as nulls. I guess it depends on how much work it will be to how many procedures. You could also do away with params and use json structure to pass down which allows flexibility at the cost of parsing it on the proc side

Comment: None of the above sounds too appealing to me to be honest. Perhaps you can have a TVP with some bit columns which says if field is used at all, but still, TVP have a fixed structures and are complicated to redeploy with new columns

Comment: I'd be inclined to put your logic in the application layer for this. It would require an additional db call to first retrieve your current values, but then you can do something like: `if (expirationDate)
    request.input('expirationDate', sql.DateTime, expirationDate) else  request.input('expirationDate', sql.DateTime, current.expirationDate);`.  So if the request body explicitly has null you pass this, but if it is missing completely you use the existing value. Then in your proc you can just do `EXPIRATION_DATE = @expirationDate`.

Comment: I don't prescribe vehemently to the mantra that application/business logic should not live in the database, but in this case I think it makes sense to keep the logic in the application and not the database. If your request allows for not all fields to be provider, then your request should cater for this requirement, and not the database. It also avoids tightly coupling this procedure to the specific call, and specifically what fields in the request are optional etc.

Comment: @GarethD Some other update procedures we have do this, but instead of making an extra DB call, the frontend just sends all the current data in the request, since it already has it. That's what I wanted to avoid, sending unnecessary data in the request. But your suggestions sounds logical.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant/common way of handling this?

Without referring to the procedure definition, what does this do?

```
UPDATE_CONTRACT(42, 'Arthur Dent', null, '2024-01-01', null)
```

And what does this do?

```
update contract
name = 'Arthur Dent',
effectiveDate = '2024-01-01'
where contract_id = 42
```

Rather than using their existing knowledge of SQL, the developer must learn a procedure (possibly many procedures) very specific to your application.

The procedure is obfuscating a very simple update statement. Get rid of the procedure and just do the update. It's simpler and easier to understand.

---

**UPDATE** now that there is more context...

In your implementation, the caller has to do a lot of work and know intimate details about the query (like the types of columns) just to use the procedure. Your database and application are wielded together; the stored procedure is just obfuscation.

Move building the query into the application. JavaScript has better facilities for handing arguments and is a better programming language in general. You'd pass in key/value pairs and use the key's existence to determine whether or not to update it.

**HOWEVER** writing a custom procedure for each operation and table is laborious, maintenance heavy, and just obfuscates the perfectly understandable SQL. Instead, use a pre-existing SQL Builder such as [knex.js](https://knexjs.org/).

```
knex('contact')
  .where({contract_id: 42})
  .update({
    nane: 'Arthur Dent',
    description: 'Mostly Harmless',
    effective_date: undefined
  })
```

You could put an `updateContract` wrapper around this, but again, the knex query is so simple this just obfuscates the query. If you really want to abstract away the details of the database, look into using an ORM and/or the [Repository Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/repository-design-pattern/).

Finally, you seem to be writing a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create%2C_read%2C_update_and_delete) API by hand. Libraries already exist to do this, for example [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

Then you can focus on writing your application logic rather than spending all that time writing your own query builder and CRUD API.

Comment: There are lots of very good reasons for using stored procedures instead of raw SQL.

Comment: @DaleK Sure. Is this one of them?

Comment: Potentially, forcing all updates through a single known point is frequently useful.

Comment: Ok, evidently code blocks don't work in comments so I will update the question with more context.

Comment: You can use single tilde code blocks in comments, but it doesn't always look great either

Comment: @Joe Thanks, answer updated. tl;dr use an existing query builder.

Comment: @DaleK But [not like this](https://youtu.be/X02EwkGqyto?si=yGd55zBEoIpqzr95).

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the suggestions. This is an old project and we cannot move away from the database for certain reasons. Stored procedures are the primary way things are done, but I'm not a fan of it. I am familiar with ORMs like TypeORM and Hibernate and I agree, they are way more convenient.

Comment: @Joe That's unfortunate. Seems you're stuck in a variation of the [lava flow antipattern](http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm). Good luck.